# Сохранить GIF в базу данных

Tags: java, android, kotlin, glide

У меня есть **ImageView**, который содержит GIF. Мне нужно сохранить его в базу данных (использую **SQLiteDatabase**), чтобы потом достать.
Как это можно сделать? Вообще возможно ли это?
Скачиваю GIF через Glide

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668/how-to-store-image-in-sqlite-database

Comment: хотя конечно надо смотреть сколько у тебя изображений будет и какой у них будет примерно размер и количество. т.к. может их будет проще хранить на файловой системе в каталоге кеша к примеру с именем хеша скажем, а в базе хранить только имя файла, как вариант.

Comment: @Yakov, это для картинки) GIF так не конвертируется

Comment: это пример как работать с блобом, в блоб все равно что сохранить, ты только бери его не из имиджвью. Если ты знаешь как сохранить, но не знаешь как достать его до того как он попадает в вью, то и вопрос надо по-другому наверное строить.

Comment: опять же смотри, глайд может кешировать твои файлы, в этом случае ты можешь хранить просто урл файла в базе и грузить его глайдом, а он уже разберется где его брать, из сети или на файловой системе.

Comment: @Yakov, а как мне сохранить и достать url кеша? Просто нигде не могу найти